# Object instantiation using Reflection works in VB.NET but not C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll, system.reflection

I'm trying to instantiate an object from a dll without referencing it. I can do it using Reflection in VB.NET but can't figure out how to do it in C#.

In VB.NET:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim bytes() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("\\path\directory\file.dll")
Dim assmb As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(bytes)
Dim myDllClass As Object = assmb.CreateInstance("myNamespace.myClass")

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim conStr As String = myDllClass.publicConString
    Dim dt As DataTable = myDllClass.MethodReturnsDatatable("select * from Part", conStr)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

In C#:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\path\directory\file.dll");
    static System.Reflection.Assembly assmb = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(bytes);
    object myDllClass = assmb.CreateInstance("myNamespace.myClass");

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conStr = myDllClass.publicConString;
        DataTable dt = myDllClass.MethodReturnsDatatable("select * from Part", conStr);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }                
}
```

I get these two errors:

> Error 1   'object' does not contain a definition for 'publicConString' and no extension method 'publicConString' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Username\Desktop\C#\FormTest\FormTest\Form1.cs 29  34  FormTest
>
> Error 2   'object' does not contain a definition for 'MethodReturnsDatatable' and no extension method 'MethodReturnsDatatable' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Username\Desktop\C#\FormTest\FormTest\Form1.cs 30  33  FormTest

Comment: If you don't make it, VB is not very strict when it comes to types.  In your C# version, try declaring `myDllClass` as `dynamic` rather than as `object`.  Haven't had too much experience with it myself (hence a comment and not an answer), but I think it will solve your problem.  If you use `Option Strict On` in your VB version, you'd see the same compiler errors.

Comment: It's C#, you can't just call methods on Objects, willy nilly.  Cast your object to the expected type and then try.  Sheesh, VB.

Comment: @Will I'm not sure he can cast it to the right type, since he's not referencing the dll

Comment: @JamesThorpe good point--he's using the name to instantiate it.  Then either split off the interface into its own assembly that both reference (in order to prevent the implementation assembly from having to be referenced) and cast to *that*, or use `dynamic` and cross your fingers.

Comment: Thanks James, that solved it. This was my first question ever so I'm not sure how to set your response as the answer.

Comment: @jessehouwing not at all - I'm just here to help and learn, rep is secondary :)  as mentioned above - I wasn't entirely sure if `dynamic` would fix it anyway!

Comment: @Will: Actually, you can do this via the 'dynamic' keyword. Not that I'm saying it's a great idea, but there are times when it's appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VB.NET will allow you to do "Late Binding" (when `option strict` is not used or when it's explicitly allowed through the project properties.) which will let the runtime check whether the object has a certain method before callign it. This is also possible in C#, but then you need to explicitly tell the runtime you want to allow this. You do it by marking the object as [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
 dynamic myDllClass = assmb.CreateInstance("myNamespace.myClass");
```

Dynamic will solve your direct issue, but it comes at a cost:

- Invoking dynamic methods is is much slower than invoking a non-dynamic method.
- Plus, your code will compile just fine, but could fail at runtime.
- And Intellisense will not be able to help you suggest the correct method names (and casing, since C# is case sensitive).

But a better solution would be, if you know the type of the class (which you do in this case, to cast it to that type (or to an Interface implemented by the class or a base class which your class extends from):

```
 myClass myDllClass = (myClass) assmb.CreateInstance("myNamespace.myClass");
```

This would require you to add an assembly reference to the project containing the `myClass` class.

You can improve your model by creating a shared assembly that contains the base class or interface:

In the shared assembly:

```
 public interface myInterface
 {
     string publicConString { get; };
     DataTable MethodReturnsDatatable(string sql, string connectionString);
 }
```

In your `file.dll`, add a reference to the assembly/project containing `myInterface`:

```
 public class myClass : myInterface{}
```

In your project consuming `myClass` also add a reference to the assembly/project containing `myInterface`:

```
 myInterface myDllClass = (myInterface) assmb.CreateInstance("myNamespace.myClass");
```

This way you don't need to have a direct reference to `file.dll`, allowing you to load different implementations at runtime, but it does ensure that you're only calling proper methods and that your code knows how to deal with it.

Comment: Note that when using `Option Strict`, late binding is not an all or nothing proposition. **Project Properties -> Compile** will allow you to treat late binding errors as warnings but leave the other types as full errors.  It also pays to look at the warning list closely to make sure that those warnings all involve this specific situation and not dozens of others,